# Position offered from 2 universities. One has already started processing my Tier 2 and I would like to withdraw

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working-visas

I had applied for a position at 2 universities. University A (UA) and University B (UB).

UA performed their processing after the application deadline very quickly and sent me an invitation for interview. I went for the interview and was selected. They notified me via email and sent me an offer via email which stated the salary and the contracted term. I replied that I am happy with this and would like to accept the position.
They also took a copy of my passport last week and said they would like to start processing my Tier 2 visa.
They also sent a hard copy of the contract to my address and asked me to sign and return it by the 1st of October. I have not yet signed the contract.

Now during this time, UB shortlisted me and sent me an invitation for interview. I went and gave the interview at UB. I was notified recently that I have been selected and they have offered a pay that is substantially higher than what UA has offered me and also their contracted term is longer than UA.

Now naturally I would like to go with UB.

So my question is, Can I, at this stage request UA to stop working on my case and that I would like to withdraw my application from them. Is it too late since they already said they were going to sponsor my Tier 2 visa?

Thank you

Comment: Check over on [Academia.se] but if I remember correctly most answers were to just contact them ASAP and withdraw your acceptance.There's been more than one question about this issue over there.

Comment: As @mkennedy said, contact them immediately and say you withdraw before they proceed with the visa (as that could have costs for them etc). However, I should stress that since you are going to accept another position at another University, you have to be very careful and diplomatic in your message as obviously you don't want to make enemies!